# Using new Facebook SDK with Google Identity Toolkit

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit

Google Identity Toolkit won't work with the new Facebook SDK (version 4+) which I need to use in my project. Does anybody else has this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Identity Toolkit is developing the next version which will support Facebook SDK v4+. Release information will be announced on the [Google Identity Toolkit forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?place=forum/google-identity-toolkit).

Comment: Thanks. So, I have to wait for it. iOs users don't have this problem and Android does. Funny situation.

Comment: Yeah. Getting this error on iOS "FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /me should contain an explicit "fields" parameter"